# photo gallery in html and css

Tags: css, media-queries

The step says that, create a media query for screens smaller than 800px in width. In that media query, create a #gallery img rule and set the width property to 50%. This will convert your gallery to a two-column layout. Based on the instruction I wrote the code as shown below but the error shows "You should add a new @media query". So how can I fix this problem?

```
 @media (max-width: 800px){
   #gallery img{
     width: 50%;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about what you want. But the width (and height) media features can be used as ranges, prefixed with min- or max- to indicate that the given value is a minimum or a maximum. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
   #gallery img{
     width: 50%;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working as tried before.